# Unable to read "request.Body" in Go Chi router

Tags: go, go-chi

Consider the following code in main/entry function

```
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.RealIP)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    r.Post("/book", controllers.CreateBook)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
```

and CreateBook Function defined as

```
    func CreateBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    var bookObj models.Book
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&bookObj)
    spew.Dump(bookObj)
    collection := db.Client.Database("bookdb").Collection("book")
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, bookObj)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(insertResult)
  }
```

Book Model

```
//exporting attributes here solved the issue
type Book struct {
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id,omitempty"`
    name   string             `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    author string             `json:"author,omitempty" bson:"author,omitempty"`
    isbn   string             `json:"isbn,omitempty" bson:"isbn,omitempty"`
}
```

However `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&bookObj)` does not parse anything as `req.Body` is empty, no error thrown, it's about chi's `Render` function.

Can anyone help me to disable `Render` and `Bind` functions of `chi`, I would like to parse the body through JSON decoders only.

Comment: How do you know `req.Body` is empty? What does the error returned from `Decode` say? What do you mean it's about Render / Bind? What have those two anything to do with this?

Comment: ... also show how you've defined the `Book` model.

Comment: I have updated questions, no error is thrown by Decode method.

Comment: ok so the first problem is that your fields are unexported. `encoding/json` doesn't work on unexported fields. First export the fields, try again, and if that doesn't fix it update the question with the progress.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Ohh, I missed that part, and after exporting fields, it resolved the problem, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting all fields of structs resolved the issue. thanks @mkopriva

```
type Book struct {
ID     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id,omitempty"`
Name   string             `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
Author string             `json:"author,omitempty" bson:"author,omitempty"`
ISBN   string             `json:"isbn,omitempty" bson:"isbn,omitempty"`
```

}